# Trouble understanding reflection

Tags: java, android

Can anyone explain this piece of code i am sort of new to java

```
Class c = Class.forName(telephony.getClass().getName());
Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
```

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: how can we declare class and methods using this syntax...

Comment: Take a look at [Java Reflection API.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/index.html)

Comment: This is called reflection. We don't declare classes and methods using this syntax. We can [only load and introspect what is already available](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)

Comment: @maddy you should include your response to `Blender` in your question as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called reflection. It is accessing classes, objects and methods at runtime rather than compile time. It is also not Android-specific.

"Java's Reflection API's makes it possible to inspect classes, interfaces, fields and methods at runtime, without knowing the names of the classes, methods etc. at compile time. It is also possible to instantiate new objects, invoke methods and get/set field values using reflection."

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html

Answer (score 3):

**Java Reflection** allows an executing Java program to examine or "introspect" upon itself, and manipulate internal properties of the program. For example, it's possible for a Java class to obtain the names of all its members and display them.

A call to `Class.forName("X")` causes the class named X to be dynamically loaded (at runtime). A call to forName("X") causes the class named X to be initialized (i.e., JVM executes all its static block after class loading). `Class.forName("X")` returns the Class object associated with the "X" class. The returned Class object is not an instance of the "x" class itself.

`Class.forName("X")` loads the class if it not already loaded. The JVM keeps track of all the classes that have been previously loaded. This method uses the classloader of the class that invokes it. The "X" is the fully qualified name of the desired class.

```
getDeclaredMethod()
```

The second step is to call a method such as getDeclaredMethod, to get a method given in argument declared by the class.

Look at this for more info [Reflection](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/)

Answer (score 2):

`telephony.getClass().getName()` extracts string that contains fully qualified class name of object `telephony`.

`Class.forName(...)` retrieves the Class object using the fully qualified name.

`c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony")`  retrieves by reflection the `Method` named `"getITelephony"`.

BTW all these may be re-written as following: `telephony.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony")`

Answer (score 1):

This returns the name of the class associated with he `telephony` variable:

```
telephony.getClass().getName()
```

This returns a reference to the class with the name you got previously:

```
telephony.getClass().getName()
```

Which is kind of pointless, because you could just do this instead:

```
Class c = telephony.getClass();
```

The second line returns a reference to a `Method` object representing the `getITelephony` method on the `c` class.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are trying to receive incoming call in android automatically...

But important point is that Google has blocked this now because ITelephony is an private API.

If you decide that this answers your question, please mark it as "accepted". This will raise both your and my reputation score.

Comment: 'Intent buttonUp = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
     buttonUp.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK));
     context.sendOrderedBroadcast(buttonUp, "android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED");'